# Dynamic relation between GOOGLE Maps API v3 and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, google-maps-api-3

I am designing my very own first web page. It's a real estate page where some users will add open house information while others can pull the info. 
The code for the database and the web is very good (after two months...) and inserting and getting data is sweet...
Now the Google maps. I am trying to have something like trulia or even the very original [housingmaps.com](http://www.housingmaps.com/) (It seems that they started the mash up, right?). crimereports.com is very nice, too.

GOAL: pull addresses from database, get long and lat from geocode, insert it back to table, display in google map. Plus: as people pan the map, new info pops into map.

Here is the code for retrieving addresses, geo code, and add lat and lng back to database.

```
<?php
//require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$username = "abc"; //personal info changed to abc
$password = "abc";
$hostname = "abc"; 
$database = "abc";
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//if (!$connection) {
  //die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
//}

define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
define("KEY", "my .............key........code");



// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM brokerstour.property WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;
$base_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters";

// Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $geocode_pending = true;

  while ($geocode_pending) {
    $address = $row["address"];
    $id = $row["id"];
    $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

    $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
    if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
      // Successful geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
      $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
      // Format: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
      $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];
      $lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];

      $query = sprintf("UPDATE property " .
             " SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " .
             " WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
      $update_result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$update_result) {
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
      }
    } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
      // sent geocodes too fast
      $delay += 100000;
    } else {
      // failure to geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
      echo "Received status " . $status . "
\n";
    }
    usleep($delay);
  }
}
?>
```

Here is what I have changed to the Google Tutorial (original code):
1) updated php: mysqli to avoid errors. Not getting more php errors. 
2) changed the url from "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY; 
TO
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters" 
trying to update code to API v3.

If I use old url, i get error 610.
With new url I get:

---

( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters&q=4200+Park+Blvd+" in C:.... on line 57
.....

### url not loading

Full disclosure: I am very new and maybe the above doesn't even make sense. However I have been stuck on this problem for a week. (By the way for those new to google maps, the book Beginning Google API 3 is a must. It does not deal with database though, but explains the google maps api very well).

Could someone please give any a hint, book, tutorial? Any help is a great help. 
Thank you for your time.

Line 57 is
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

Answer (score 2):

The  `$base_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters";` You do not specify output.It should be either `xml` or `jason`. Also the parameters you pass are address and either `sensor = false` or `sensor = true`

**EDIT**

Remove

```
$geocode_pending = true;
while ($geocode_pending) {
```

**END EDIT**

```
$q = $row["address"];
$base_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=";
$request_url = $base_url.urlencode($q)."&sensor=false";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
if($xml->status=="OK"){
    // Successful geocode
    $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
```

**EDIT**

```
    echo $lat.","$lng."<br>";//
    } 
    }
```

Remove rest of code and make sure this works before incementally adding rest of code

Comment: Thank you for your time! The error message now seems to be closer to the solution. First of all, I replaced the line (url $base_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=";) with your 8-line code. I am new to this.... This is what i get now:  Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:...on line 48 (which is your first line). Also I get this error: (Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:.... on line 67 (line 67: $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;). Finally, I get this message: "Address ... failed to geocoded. Received status ". It reads every address though!

Comment: What are you getting for `$q = $row["address"];` Try `echo $q;`

Comment: Thank you for helping. Error message: "Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\test\geocode.php". I tried the to print "q", nothing happens. The code reads all rows of addresses and returns the same message: "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\...". I guess code and mysql is fine. The problem is the connection with google and it seems the url is the main obstacle. I tried the Google V2 code with the key and it gives 610 error. With V3 code and your help and I get these errors above. Better than before when it was not even reading mysql. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: The url in my answer is correct if you type it into your browser with an address it will provide data.The rest of your code must be causing the problem.Try limiting query to say `LIMIT 1,10` . Comment out `while ($geocode_pending) {` and its closing `}` Comment out from `$query = sprintf("UPDATE property " .` to the end. and echo out    `$lat & $lng` .Get this piece of code to work & then build up  gradually

Comment: Thank you. I will try. I was trying to remove the delay and some other parts to see where the problems is. It reads the table and brings the addresses correctly. But it does not pull lat and lnt. I will try your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: How did you test the url? when I put it in the address bar, I get access denied. I tried with "+" and without. If I put nothing, browser generates "%20" between the names and numbers. They both get the following message: "<GeocodeResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
</GeocodeResponse>"

Comment: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=paisley&sensor=false` for paisley

Comment: ** Trying to get property of non-object ** This is the message a I get around " // Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address " in the code above. Does anyone has a clue? Code reads all rows in the table, but does not geocode them. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That one works. I did a minor change: echo $lat . "\n" ;
 echo $lng . "<br>"; that brings the values for lat and lnt.

Comment: There is another fix too:  $loc_address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);$location = $loc_address;
   echo $location."<br>"; than the "q" and urlencode aren't needed anymore. That was one of the sources of the problem. I am still working on the rest of the code. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial success. 
This code accomplishes:
a) get addresses from table;
b) get lat and lnt from google;
c) insert data back into table.

I still need to work on the delay. Besides, I am a 3 month old programmer... and to get the above working took me two long weeks... I left the delay in there just for reference (it was tutorial from Google with changes form other people in the web.)

I tried to vote up the answer from Mr. Strachan, but I lack reputation inside stack overflow... Could not do it. That fix also works. Thank you for your time.

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'rxxt', 'xxxxxxx');
if(!$conn)
 {
   echo "Database Error.";
 }
 else
 {
   echo "Connected.";
   mysql_select_db('YOUR TABLE', $conn);
   $query = "SELECT * from YOUR TABLE";
   $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die($query.mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 

      $address = $row['address'];
      $id = $row['id'];

      $loc_address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); //to replace spaces by '+' signs
          $location = $loc_address;
      echo $location."<br>";
      $delay = 0;  // this delay is here just to avoid errors - 
          $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$location."&sensor=false";
          echo $url;
            $output=file_get_contents($url);
            $out= json_decode($output);
            $lat = $out->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
            $lng = $out->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
            echo '<br>Lat is '. $lat;
            echo '<br>Long is '. $lng;


       $query = sprintf("UPDATE YOUR TABLE " .
             " SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " .
             " WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
           $update_result = mysql_query($query);

      echo "Successfully inserted.";
    // Below is just for reference - they say we need the delay. The may problem: does not get the status to compare to 200, 620, etc.   
    /*$status = $xml->Response->Status->code;  
    if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
            // Successful geocode
            echo '<br />successfull geocode</strong><br />';
            $geocode_pending = false;
    }
    else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
         // sent geocodes too fast
         $delay += 100000;
            } else {
         // failure to geocode
         $geocode_pending = false;
         echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
         echo "Received status " . $status . "
        \n";
          }*/
    usleep($delay); 
    }
 }
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```